# Loading multiple files from Parse on IOS - performance

Tags: ios, parse-platform

We have an array of images > 10 and we would like to pull down the data from Parse.com and store it in core data. It seems to be taking a long time to accomplish this. Also the UI will block a few times during this process.

Is there way of finding out whether the downloads are happening in parallel, and what might be causing the UI to be blocked?

Below is an excerpt of the code:

```
NSDictionary *dic= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:str,str2, nil],@"flowIds",flowAndDateObj.dateUpdated ,@"syncDate", nil];
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"syncFlows" withParameters:dic block:^(id object, NSError *error)
{
    NSArray *arrResults=(NSArray *) object;
    NSLog(@"Count: %d",arrResults.count);
    if (arrResults.count>0)
    {
         for (PFObject *object1 in arrResults) {
            if ([object1[@"images"] count] !=0)
            {
                PFObject *object2= object1[@"images"][0];
                PFFile *imageFile = object2[@"imageFile"];
                [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:(NSData *data, NSError *error){
                          //Slow.
                }];
            }
         }
    } 
];
```

Thanks in advance for helping out.

Comment: What does the syncFlows cloud function do?

Comment: Hi Marius. Its returning an array of objects which have been updated since the last sync date.

Answer (score 0):

If they are big files, it will probably take some time to get all the data.  If you want to track the progress, you can use this:

```
[imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    // slow
} progressBlock:^(int percentDone) {
    NSLog(@"We are: %i percent done", percentDone);
}];
```

Not sure if it's a solution, but it might help you trace the problem or notify the user of status so it doesn't feel too laggy.  Users love progress bars!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. We will put in some lil animation to keep them entertained.